# Get tenant name using /sites/root Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I have the following code to get hostname using /sites/root Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
        public async Task<string> GetHostNameAsync(string token)
        {
            var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            var _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent, _expandoObjectConverter);
            var sharePointSites = responseJson;
            var siteCollection = sharePointSites.siteCollection;
            var hostName = siteCollection.hostname;
            return hostName.ToString();
        }
```

MS Graph Explorer:

[image]

Is there an alternate way to get hostname without using this API?

Comment: What are your requirements? Why do not you want to use this endpoint?

Comment: I want to get the sitecollection -> host name `microsoft.sharepoint.com` to find out the user tenant

Comment: If I decode this token, I see a key called upn with value "xxx@tenant.com". Can I update the code to decode the token and get this key value and parse the tenant name?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [get organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

```
GET /organization
```

You should be able to read `id`, `displayName` and `verifiedDomains` properties with even with the basic permission `User.Read`.

[displayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) represents the name of the tenant.